# "HTTP response detected" errors in Google Tag Assistant, do I need to fix them? (and how?)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, error

I am getting the following error by Google Tag Assistant:

> No HTTP response detected

1. My data is still showing up in GA main dashboard. So do I even need to fix the error?
2. How do I fix it? I installed GA using plugin for WordPress so it wasn't a manual installation.

Answer (score 2):

1. *My data is still showing up in GA main dashboard. So do I even need to fix the error?*

   Are you sure it is data for your site that is showing up in the reports, and not spam data?
   Check the Audience > Technology > Network report (change the Primary Dimension to Hostname) and ensure it is only data from your own domain and any other relevant/valid hostnames that is being tracked.
2. *How do I fix it? I installed GA using plugin for Wordpress so it wasn't a manual installation.*

   - Make sure the website URL entered in GA Property settings is the same as the url entered in the WP Admin Settings > General for Site Address (URL)
   - Ensure you do not have another browser addon that is causing an issue with Google Tag Assistant. Temp disable them and restart browser, see if the issue persists. If the issue doesn't persist, start re-enabling the addons again, one at a time, and retesting the site with GTA, until you find the addon that is causing the issue.
   - Make sure you aren't logged into your site and clear cache and cookies before rechecking the site with Tag Assistant. Often GA plugins will block logged in Admins from being tracked by default (unless you change the plugin settings), which can sometimes result in GTA giving unexpected results.
   - Check that you have set the plugin to add the a recent version of tracking code (not ga.js) and it is adding it to the head of the site, not the footer.